# Azure ServiceBus: Receiving messages from a session of a queue in a callback

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I tried to use Queue​Client.​Accept​Message​Session​Async(sessionID)  to receive messages from just one session using Receive().
Is there any mechanism in this, where I can register the callbacks so that I receive message on this callback for this session alone.

I tried using Session Handler for this where I can receive message on the callback onMessageAsync() but the problem there was that I was getting messages for all the session on that queue client and not just single sessionId.

Comment: What client do you use, WindowsAzure.ServiceBus or Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus(part of Microsoft.Servicebus dll)

Comment: Raise an issue in the repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues. If your client specified a session ID, no messages from other sessions should be received.